# The interval of results from Google's activity recognition isn't regular

Tags: android, intervals, activity-recognition

I was working on google's activity recognition and finally I got results from this service.

However, The function `requestActivityUpdates(long detectionIntervalMillis, PendingIntent callbackIntent)` doesn't seem to work correctly. The detection interval is not regular and decreases to 30~50 seconds when my current activity is changing. It doesn't work like the live demo on google I/O 2013 ([Google I/O 2013 Location API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc), from 27:47 to 28:45). Does anyone have same issue on it?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue right now, activity updates are delivered slower than ``detectionIntervalMillis``, especially when activity is changing, even if I set ``detectionIntervalMillis = 0``

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a bit confusing but the variable `long detectionIntervalMillis` does not fix the interval - it sets the maximum interval between two updates.

As it's said in the official documentation:

> Activities may be received more frequently than the `detectionIntervalMillis` parameter if another application has also requested activity updates at a faster rate. It may also receive updates faster when the activity detection service receives a signal that the current activity may change, such as if the device has been still for a long period of time and is then unplugged from a phone charger.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition.html#requestActivityUpdates(long,%20android.app.PendingIntent/)

Comment: The question is more about why activity recognition is slower than ``detectionIntervalMillis``

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the build() part on onCreate directly try adding the method below and call it on onCreate(). And try to trace the code from [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/ActivityRecognition/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/activityrecognition/MainActivity.java) I got the code stripped down from that sample.

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .build();
}
```

and add `buildGoogleApiClient()` to your onCreate method ;) this works great for me!