# Android Activity Recognition updates are not regular

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303382/the-interval-of-results-from-googles-activity-recognition-isnt-regular).

I am experiencing that Activity Recognition updates are not delivered on a regular basis. The power saving mode on my phone is disabled and I set the fastest possible detection interval (0), yet sometimes intents are not delivered for more than 10-20 seconds. It seems the delays mostly happen during an activity transition (e.g., `still -> in vehicle`), but this is just a hypothesis.

In my application I need be able to set a strict upper bound for the interval between intents, has anyone achieved something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may come a little late. However yes this is normal. I have noticed that there is a delay during a transition from activity A to activity B (e.g. from still to walking) while there is generally no delay  when the activity is constant. I guess this is because the sensor tries to collect as much evidence as possible in case of activity change (e.g. to avoid returning false positives). I doubt there is any way to change that.